# Adding User's First Name to Devise Confirmation Email Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm running Rails 4.2.0 with the latest version of Devise.

I'm using the confirmable module - so after a user registers they are sent a confirmation email.

Here's the view code for that (in Slim... not ERB)

```
p 
  | Hi
  = @user.first_name
  | ,

p In order for me to send you the details, I'm going to need you to confirm your email address by clicking the link below: 
= link_to "#{confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)}", confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)
```

Here's the Users Controller code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

There is a first name column in the database (migration has been run); however, this doesn't work. The place where the users first name should be is blank.

How can I configure the view to include the users first name?

Comment: Are you sure that first_name is stored correctly in db?

Comment: The first_name is actually not being saved in the database (or at least not saved correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some digging through the Devise Gem and found that I needed to over-ride the following controller actions (app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb):

```
 private

 def sign_up_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 end

 def account_update_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
 end
```

...and ensure that my application is using my new Registrations controller with this in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'user/registrations' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Devise uses resources to abstract the thing that it is managing.

Assuming your @resource is being set correctly, you should be able to do

```
@resource.first_name
```

Comment: this isn't working. do I need to change something in the confirmations controller?

Comment: In that same form if you are using pry, put a binding.pry to evaluate your resources.  If not do '@user.inspect' and then '@resource.inspect' in the template to see what they are.  - note single quotes are only way i could get this to save.  Ignore those around the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

current_user.first_name has worked for me in the past.  Any good?